amending documents using outlines package to create nested list with numbers and letters
I'm looking for advice. I have a couple of long documents where I use the outlines package. I use the default enumeration, which is a black dot for the first level and then a long minus sign for the second level (I don't use more than two levels in all of the documents). I am a bit lost now since I want to change this enumeration style in all of my documents to a number in the first level and a letter in the second level, however, I want the enumeration of the number to continue throughout the document.
Maybe I'm asking for too much, but I'd also like to be able to label my items as indicated below. Maybe I used the wrong package. Basically this is how the documents look like, \begin{outline} after \begin{outline}:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{outlines}

\begin{document}
\begin{outline}
    \1 The first bullet point should be a number.
    \2 The second one should be a letter. %\label{this should output 1(a) when I refer to it}
\end{outline}
Some text or perhaps a new section.
\begin{outline}
    \1 Continue the enumeration of the number.
    \2 Start over enumeration of the letter.
\end{outline}
\end{document}


Be aware that this affects all enumerate environments. So if you want to use them in your document too, you should perhaps define special lists, see the enumitem documentation.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{outlines}
\renewcommand{\outlinei}{enumerate} % see docu of outline, page 2
\renewcommand{\outlineii}{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*),resume=outline}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\alph*.,ref=\arabic{enumi}(\theenumii)}

\begin{document}
\begin{outline}
    \1 The first bullet point which is numbered.
    \2 The second one which has a letter.\label{blub}
\end{outline}
\begin{outline}
    \1 Continue enumeration of the number.
    \2 Start over enumeration of the letter.
\end{outline}
\begin{outline}
    \1 Continue enumeration of the number.
    \2 Start over enumeration of the letter.
\end{outline}

\ref{blub}
\end{document}


